# Android SQLite issue table … has no column named

Tags: android, sqlite

I have uninstalled app, created new emulator but problem is still there i have no clue so time for internet to help :).
I have a column named "sms_sentdate" in the log this is the column that goes missing, while i have checked values that is ok, problem lies somewhere in schema that i can't figure out.

While you guys are at it, please advice about how can i tell app that schema has been updated if my current method is wrong.

```
public class SMSdb extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private final static String DB_NAME = "SMSDB";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 4;

private static final String KEY_ID = "sms_id";
private static final String KEY_Text = "sms_text";
private static final String KEY_SMSReceiver = "sms_reciever";
private static final String KEY_Recurrence = "sms_recurrence_id";
private static final String KEY_SentDate = "sms_sentdate";
private static final String TABLE_SMS = "sms";
private static final String[] COLUMNS = { KEY_ID, KEY_Text, KEY_SMSReceiver, KEY_Recurrence, KEY_SentDate};

public final static String DB_SMSdb_TABLE_CREATE = "create table sms " +
        "("+KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
            KEY_Text +" text not null, "+
            KEY_SMSReceiver + " text not null,"+
            KEY_Recurrence+" integer);"+
            KEY_SentDate+" text);";

public SMSdb(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);      
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Database", "Database creating");
    database.execSQL(DB_SMSdb_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sms");
    onCreate(database);     
}

public void addSms(SMS sms){
   Log.d("addSMS", sms.toString()); 
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(KEY_Text, sms.getText());
   values.put(KEY_SMSReceiver, sms.getSmsReceiver());
   values.put(KEY_Recurrence, sms.getSms_recurrence_id());
   values.put(KEY_SentDate, sms.getSmsSentDate());

   db.insert(TABLE_SMS,
           null,
           values);
   db.close(); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
KEY_Recurrence+" integer);"+
KEY_SentDate+" text);";
```

with

```
KEY_Recurrence+" integer,"+
KEY_SentDate+" text);";
```

The SQL is terminated on the first `;` and any remaining SQL is not executed so you didn't get a syntax error about the dangling column specifications.

Comment: Damn it!! **Bloody Semicolon**

Comment: Thanks! @laalto, i checked everything except for **;**, now i am ashamed :P